# Unable to pin button towrads right corner in tableView Cell

Tags: swift, uitableview, button, autolayout

I tried many ways to pin the button towards right corner of the table view cell.It's fits properly only for one device segment for iPhone SE/5s button is not visible.

I had given equal width  & height alogn with top and right constraints.

Below is the screen shot of auto layout segment.
[image]

Comment: I tried unchecking Contraints to Margin too. Still same result.

Comment: But for iPhone 5s/SE button isn't visible it's towards the out of th screen boundary.

Comment: Does your cell have other inner views? If so, you probably should show us full layout rather than just single button. A simple test is following: create another cell with just this button and nothing else with the same constraints. Does it work as expected? If so, then the issue is with interference with other inner views and their constraints.

Comment: can you show us how it looks on the iPhone while the app is being run ?

Comment: Yes u are correct Dark some other inner views were changing the layout and making it disturbed. I did a simple test as u mentioned. Now i am able to get desired output whet i need. Thank you very much.